# Logback buffer messages before HDD is available

Tags: java, kotlin, logging, logback, slf4j

So i have an embeedded java device that runs code as early as possible after boot. But HDD is not available immediately.

I've found out that using logback with xml configuration is not working as whenever it starts it checks for existance of log file which is not possible as HDD is not mounted yet.

So I've programatically added FileAppender when HDD is started. But this results in lots of messages being lost as there is no appender when the device boots and I am unable to get logs from the time when it booted till the HDD is available.

Is there a way to buffer these messages and print them to the file once the HDD is booted?

my way of initing appender:

```kotlin
fun startLogger() {
    logger.debug("Starting HDD logger")
    val lc = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory() as LoggerContext
    lc.reset()
    try {
        val root = lc.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)
        logFileAppender.apply {
            context = lc
            name = "logFile"
            file = "/mnt/hdd/cz.myq.roger.ricoh/logs/logfile.log"
            encoder = PatternLayoutEncoder().apply {
                context = lc
                pattern = "%-12date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{12} %-5level - %msg%n"
                start()
            }
            isAppend = true
            rollingPolicy = TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>().apply {
                context = lc
                fileNamePattern = "/mnt/hdd/cz.myq.roger.ricoh/logs/logfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip"
                maxHistory = 7
                setTotalSizeCap(FileSize.valueOf("100MB"))
            }.also {
                it.setParent(this@apply)
                it.start()
            }
            start()
        }
        root.addAppender(logFileAppender)

        lc.getLogger(DNSIncoming::class.java).level = Level.WARN
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.error("Error starting log", e)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not Java. Please tag the appropriate language (I guess it's kotlin, but I won't change it myself because I'm not sure).

Comment: yes the code is written in kotlin but the question is about logback for java. I will add the kotlin tag

Comment: There's no way to do this out of the box. Logback appenders are initialized before they accept any messages. So you'd need to write your own appender, which attempts to open the file if it's not already open. If that fails, then you'd add the message to a thread-safe buffer. If it succeeds, you'd write all the messages in the buffer. Once the file has been opened, you can just write the messages normally.

Comment: @kdgregory I've done it according to your comment. I've extended RollingFileAppender and override the openFile and subAppend methods to stash logs until HDD is initialized. once initialized i call the super.openFile method cycle through the stash to append it. once done i allow the subAppend method to call super.subApend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer. I've followed the @kdgregory comment and implemented it this way:

```
class MyAppender : RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>() {
    private val buffer = mutableListOf<ILoggingEvent>()

    fun initHdd() {
        if (hddInit) return
        try {
            super.openFile(file)
            hddInit = true
            buffer.forEach {
                append(it)
            }
            buffer.clear()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }


    override fun openFile(file_name: String?): Boolean {
        if (!hddInit) outputStream = NullOutputStream()
        else super.openFile(file_name)
        return true
    }


    override fun subAppend(event: ILoggingEvent) {
        if (hddInit) super.subAppend(event)
        else {
            if (buffer.size >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) return
            buffer.add(event)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
        private const val MAX_TAG_LENGTH = 23
        var hddInit = false
    }
}
```